# Arrangement of font shorthand in css

Tags: css, fonts, shorthand

Why should the shorthand for font property be in this sequence?

font: font-style  font-weight  font-size  font-family

Why should the style and weight come before the size?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer might not be what you're looking for, but it is an answer nonetheless.

The reason why is because that is how the specification defines the `font` property.

```
Value:      [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit
```

The specification states that font-style, font-variant, and font-weight must come before font-size.

The specification further states:

> The syntax of this property is based on a traditional typographical shorthand notation to set multiple properties related to fonts.

So, while many short-hand properties typically only require a specific order when the values are of a similar type, the font shorthand is defined in a specific order because they wanted to keep consistency with how other applications and software had defined font properties.